# Cluster disk IO - NO DATA Cloudera Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, cluster-computing, cloudera, cloudera-cdh

I am new in that area and have some problems with my hadoop cluster.
I am installed CDH with Cloudera Manager on the cluster with 7 servers.
Inspection of all hasts was successful.

Image of successful inspection

[image: Image of successful inspection]

In the installation process, there were some errors, but after the restarting of the cluster they disappeared and I've fixed the other health issues.
Now the status of my cluster looks like next image:

Status of my hadoop cluster

[image: Ststus of my hadoop cluster]

But i still can't watch the Cluster disk IO statistic because is NO DATA.
How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Sorry, forgot paste screen of my hadoop general panel https://imgur.com/a/JmV2E

Comment: You need to actually write data to disk to see disk io